# Making the ImageView at least 50% of the screen

Tags: android, xml, android-imageview

Please have a look at the below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/image_background"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/mmm"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l22Parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            android:id="@+id/step18button1"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"
            android:layout_below="@+id/step18textView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2"
            android:id="@+id/step18button2"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/step18button1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button1"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"/>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3"
            android:id="@+id/step18button3"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button2"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button2"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"/>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4"
            android:id="@+id/step18button4"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button3"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button3"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"/>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5"
            android:id="@+id/step18button5"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button4"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button4"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button4"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"/>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="6"
            android:id="@+id/step18button6"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button5"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button5"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button5"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"/>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="7"
            android:id="@+id/step18button7"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button6"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button6"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button6"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"/>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="8"
            android:id="@+id/step18button8"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button7"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button7"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button7"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"/>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="9"
            android:id="@+id/step18button9"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button8"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button8"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button8"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The UI generated by the above is below
[image]

However I wanted the image to take at least 50% of the screen. The layout doesn't matter, any layout is fine, however in any mobile device it should be around 50% of the screen (50% is a rough value, it can be 60% etc). How to achieve my requirement?

### The image I use can be found here - http://iespressolife.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Malabar-InHouse-9423_1450_906px-1024x640.jpg

**UPDATE**

User "Arpit Patel"s answer is correct but it was incomplete. Below is the correct version.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/white">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_background"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/mmm" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l22Parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image_background"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/step18button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/step18textView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/step18button2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/step18button1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/step18button3"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="3"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/step18button4"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="4"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/step18button5"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button4"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button4"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="5"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/step18button6"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button5"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button5"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="6"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/step18button7"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button6"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button6"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button6"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="7"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/step18button8"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button7"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button7"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button7"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="8"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/step18button9"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button8"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button8"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="9"
            android:textSize="13dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use `linear layout` instead of `Relative layout`  ..... and use property `weight =1` in the `image view` and child `linear layout`

Comment: See my answer any let me know.

Comment: @PeakGen check my answer i edit answer..

Comment: @sushildlh: Tried. Now the image is too large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See with proof 50% of screen covered by image.

[image]

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_background"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@drawable/a" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/l22Parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image_background"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/step18button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="39dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/step18textView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="13dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/step18button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="39dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/step18button1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="2"
        android:textSize="13dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/step18button3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="39dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="3"
        android:textSize="13dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/step18button4"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="39dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="4"
        android:textSize="13dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/step18button5"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="39dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button4"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="5"
        android:textSize="13dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/step18button6"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="39dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button5"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="6"
        android:textSize="13dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/step18button7"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="39dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button6"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button6"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="7"
        android:textSize="13dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/step18button8"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="39dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button7"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button7"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button7"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="8"
        android:textSize="13dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/step18button9"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="39dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button8"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button8"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button8"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="9"
        android:textSize="13dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The image covered the entire screen.

Comment: without apply this code don't judge me. that's screen shot mistake but code was right

Comment: You are testing your solution with the android icon, which is of course small. Test with a real image. The image covers a large area of the screen.

Comment: here is the image - http://iespressolife.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Malabar-InHouse-9423_1450_906px-1024x640.jpg

Comment: Since your layout height is 0dp, I am getting a blank screen. When adjusted, it is too large.

Comment: See i added screen shot for proof. it mean it's works 100%percent.

Comment: whats your root layout?

Comment: LinearLayout i used.

Comment: Answer is correct, but incomplete. I fixed some places as well.

Comment: what did you fixed by the way??

Comment: So it will helpful for me in future.

Comment: @ArpitPatel: The fixed code in my question. The height should be specified, `layout_weight` values had to be adjusted.

Answer (score 1):

try this xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:background="@android:color/white">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/mmm"
        android:id="@+id/image_background"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/l22Parent"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:layout_below="@+id/image_background">

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            android:id="@+id/step18button1"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"
            android:layout_below="@+id/step18textView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2"
            android:id="@+id/step18button2"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/step18button1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button1"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"/>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3"
            android:id="@+id/step18button3"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button2"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button2"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"/>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4"
            android:id="@+id/step18button4"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button3"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button3"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"/>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5"
            android:id="@+id/step18button5"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button4"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button4"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button4"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"/>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="6"
            android:id="@+id/step18button6"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button5"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button5"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button5"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"/>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="7"
            android:id="@+id/step18button7"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button6"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button6"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button6"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"/>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="8"
            android:id="@+id/step18button8"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button7"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button7"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button7"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"/>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="9"
            android:id="@+id/step18button9"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/step18button8"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/step18button8"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/step18button8"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No good. Copied and pasted your code, the entire screen is now white

Comment: Not a good solution. The image is same size just the top margin is bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Just set

```
android:weight="0.5"
```

Both inside your ImageView and LinearLayout tag. You will get your image fill with half of your screen and everything others which have inside the linear layout will take other half of the screen.

Comment: This will not work because he uses a `RelativeLayout` as parent ;)

Answer (score 0):

Pin the `LinearLayout` at the bottom and tell your `ImageView` to appear above it. 
You'll need to delete the `layout_below` attribute, of course.

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <ImageView 
        layout:above_layout="@+id/yourLinearLayout"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can tell the `ImageView` to center itself in the space, crop it etc. Also, you can give your ´LinearLayout` a top margin to become bigger.